# List of figures not taking ifmmode into account?

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\cma#1{$A_{c}(#1)$}

\def\cmbs#1{B_{c_{\mathcal{L}}}^{#1}}
\def\cmb#1{\ifmmode\cmbs{#1}\else$\cmbs{#1}$\fi}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{\cma{\cmb{+}}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When trying to compile it (the second time to get the list of figures), I get:

> ! Missing $ inserted.
>
> <inserted text>
>
> l.1 ...es $A_{c}($B_{c_{\mathcal {L}}}^{+}$)$}}{1}

If I comment `\listoffigures`, everything works fine. When I look at the `.lof` file, I see:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces $A_{c}($B_{c_{\mathcal {L}}}^{+}$)$}}{1}
```

Which seems to imply that the `\ifmmode` command did not work properly...

Is there any way to work around that without having to explicitly use `\cma{\cmbs{+}}`?

Comment: @campa Thanks, `\ensuremath` did the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When LaTeX writes the line for the table of contents it is *not* in math mode.

You could define

```
\newcommand{\cma}[1]{\ensuremath{A_{c}(#1)}}
\newcommand{\cmb}[1]{\ensuremath{B_{c_{\mathcal{L}}}^{#1}}}
```

and then

```
\caption{\cma{\cmb{+}}}
```

will work. On the other hand, I see no improvement over

```
\newcommand{\cma}[1]{A_{c}(#1)}
\newcommand{\cmb}[1]{B_{c_{\mathcal{L}}}^{#1}}
```

and the more semantic

```
\caption{$\cma{\cmb{1}}$}
```

*Avoid* `\def`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with `ensuremath`. I don't want to use `$\cma{\cmb{+}}$` because `\cma` and `\cmb` are basically placeholders for algorithm names, and I have yet to decide their final value (and I don't want to have to replace `$\cma{\cmb{1}}$` by `\cma{\cmb{1}}` everywhere if I decide not to use math-mode for the algorithm names).